# Closest to Another Vector Within a Given Angle

Tags: vectors

Given:

- 3 component vectors: $\vec x$ and $\vec y$
- Angle $\theta$
- The angle between $\vec x$ and $\vec y$ is greater than $\theta$

Find a 3 component vector $\vec z$ such that $\vec z$ is in the plane defined by $\vec x$ and $\vec y$ between $\vec x$ and $\vec y$, but the angle between $\vec x$ and $\vec z$ is exactly $\theta$.

If it matters the magnitude of $\vec z$ should be equal to the magnitude of the smaller of $\vec x$ and $\vec y$.

My question is: **What's the equation that I'd use to find $\vec z$?**

Component-wise calculations don't really make sense, cause I can't get the angle between single components, but this doesn't seem like a matrix question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\vec{z}=a\vec{x}+b\vec{y}$ such a vector, we must have
\begin{align*}
\vec{z}\cdot\vec{x}&=\|\vec{z}\|\|\vec{x}\|\cos \theta\\
a\vec{x}\cdot\vec{x}+b\vec{y}\cdot\vec{x}&=\|\vec{z}\|\|\vec{x}\|\cos\theta...(1)
\end{align*}
Let $\alpha$ the angle between $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$, we also need
\begin{align*}
\vec{z}\cdot\vec{y}&= \|\vec{z}\|\|\vec{y}\|\cos(\alpha-\theta)\\
a\vec{x}\cdot\vec{y}+b\vec{y}\cdot\vec{y}&=\|\vec{z}\|\|\vec{y}\|\cos(\alpha-\theta)...(2)
\end{align*}
Then, we need solve for $a$ and $b$ equations $(1)$ and $(2)$.
If also $\|\vec{z}\|=\|\vec{x}\|$ is needed we get the system of two linear equations
\begin{align*}
(\vec{x}\cdot\vec{x})\,\color{blue}{a}+(\vec{y}\cdot\vec{x})\,\color{blue}{b}&=\|\vec{x}\|^2\cos\theta\\
(\vec{x}\cdot\vec{y})\,\color{blue}{a}+(\vec{y}\cdot\vec{y})\,\color{blue}{b}&=\|\vec{x}\|\|\vec{y}\|\cos(\alpha-\theta)
\end{align*}

Comment: I understand that you distributed $\vec{v}$ to get a left hand side of: $a\vec{x}\cdot\vec{x}+b\vec{y}\cdot\vec{x}$ I don't get how you eliminated $\|\vec{v}\|$ on the right hand side: $\|\vec{x}\|^2\cos\theta$

Comment: I am using $\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{z}$, hence I take $\|\mathbf{v}\|=\|\mathbf{z}\|=\|\mathbf{x}\|$

Comment: I've gone ahead to accept your answer, as it is the correct solution, I've put an explanation of my understanding below. If you have a moment to go through and certify it that would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is an explanation of [MarioG](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/67622/mario-g)'s answer which is the best way to find this.

The goal is to find magnitudes $a$ and $b$ such that: $a\vec{x} + b\vec{y} = \vec{z}$
[image: ax + by = z]

We'll need to find $\phi$ where the angle between $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$ is $\theta + \phi$. Since $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$ are known we can use the law of cosines to find the angle between them: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VectorAngle.html

Now we can use the system of equations to solve for $a$ and $b$:

$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}\|\vec{x}\| = \|\vec{z}\|\\
a\vec{x} + b\vec{y} = \vec{z}\\
\vec{x} \cdot \vec{z} = \|\vec{x}\|\|\vec{z}\|\cos\theta\\
\vec{y} \cdot \vec{z} = \|\vec{y}\|\|\vec{z}\|\cos\phi\end{array}\right.$$

Simplifying out $\vec{z}$ this becomes:

$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}a\vec{x} \cdot \vec{x} + b\vec{x} \cdot \vec{y} = \|\vec{x}\|^2\cos\theta\\
a\vec{x} \cdot \vec{y} + b\vec{y} \cdot \vec{y} = \|\vec{x}\|\|\vec{y}\|\cos\phi\end{array}\right.$$

Now we'll define some constants to make simplification bearable:

- $k_1 = \vec{x} \cdot \vec{x}$
- $k_2 = \vec{x} \cdot \vec{y}$
- $k_3 = \|\vec{x}\|^2\cos\theta$
- $k_4 = \vec{y} \cdot \vec{y}$
- $k_5 = \|\vec{x}\|\|\vec{y}\|\cos\phi$

So our system of equations using these constants is:

$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}ak_1 + bk_2 = k_3\\
ak_2 + bk_4 = k_5\end{array}\right.$$

Solving for $a$ and $b$ our system becomes:

$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}a = \frac{k_3 - bk_2}{k_1}\\
b = \frac{k_5 - ak_2}{k_4}\end{array}\right.$$

We'll substitute for $b$ to solve for $a$:

1. $$a = \frac{k_3 - k_2\left(\frac{k_5 - ak_2}{k_4}\right)}{k_1}$$
2. $$a = \frac{\frac{k_3k_4 - k_2k_5 + ak_2k_2}{k_4}}{k_1}$$
3. $$a = \frac{k_3k_4 - k_2k_5 + ak_2k_2}{k_1k_4}$$
4. $$a = \frac{k_3k_4 - k_2k_5}{k_1k_4} + a\left(\frac{k_2k_2}{k_1k_4}\right)$$
5. $$a - a\left(\frac{k_2k_2}{k_1k_4}\right) = \frac{k_3k_4 - k_2k_5}{k_1k_4}$$
6. $$a\left(1 - \frac{k_2k_2}{k_1k_4}\right) = \frac{k_3k_4 - k_2k_5}{k_1k_4}$$
7. $$a\left(\frac{k_1k_4 - k_2k_2}{k_1k_4}\right) = \frac{k_3k_4 - k_2k_5}{k_1k_4}$$
8. $$a(k_1k_4 - k_2k_2) = k_3k_4 - k_2k_5$$
9. $$a = \frac{k_3k_4 - k_2k_5}{k_1k_4 - k_2k_2}$$

Plugging this back in to the equation that was solved for $b$ we get:

$$b = \frac{k_5 - k_2\left(\frac{k_3k_4 - k_2k_5}{k_1k_4 - k_2k_2}\right)}{k_4}$$

Removing the constant simplification:

$$a = \frac{\vec{y} \cdot \vec{y}\|\vec{x}\|^2\cos\theta - \vec{x} \cdot \vec{y}\|\vec{x}\|\|\vec{y}\|\cos\phi}{(\vec{x} \cdot \vec{x})(\vec{y} \cdot \vec{y}) - (\vec{x} \cdot \vec{y})^2}$$

$$b = \frac{\|\vec{x}\|\|\vec{y}\|\cos\phi - \vec{x} \cdot \vec{y}\left(\frac{\vec{y} \cdot \vec{y}\|\vec{x}\|^2\cos\theta - \vec{x} \cdot \vec{y}\|\vec{x}\|\|\vec{y}\|\cos\phi}{(\vec{x} \cdot \vec{x})(\vec{y} \cdot \vec{y}) - (\vec{x} \cdot \vec{y})^2}\right)}{\vec{y} \cdot \vec{y}}$$

Now an amazing simplification would be to normalize $\vec x$ and $\vec y$ before calculation. In which case, $\|\vec x\|$, $\|\vec y\|$, $\vec x \cdot \vec x$, and $\vec y \cdot \vec y$ are all 1. Which simplifies the above equations to:

$$a = \frac{\cos \theta - \vec x \cdot \vec y \cos \phi}{1 - (\vec x \cdot \vec y)^2}$$

$$b = \cos \phi - \vec x \cdot \vec y\left(\frac{\cos \theta - \vec x \cdot \vec y \cos \phi}{1 - (\vec x \cdot \vec y)^2}\right)$$

$b$ can be further simplified by distributing $-\vec x \cdot \vec y$ and moving $\cos \phi$ into the numerator:

$$b = \frac{\cos \phi - \vec x \cdot \vec y \cos \theta}{1 - (\vec x \cdot \vec y)^2}$$

So our final answer is:

$$\vec z = \frac{\vec x(\cos \theta - \vec x \cdot \vec y \cos \phi) + \vec y(\cos \phi - \vec x \cdot \vec y \cos \theta)}{1 - (\vec x \cdot \vec y)^2}$$